# Full java code from Netbeans Project

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

How can I get the full java code of a netbeans project? I have created a project for a contest, but need to submit the whole code. In Netbeans alot of the libraries and classes code is hidden. I need to submit all this. Even if a plugin needs to be installed.

Thank You :)

Comment: Unless your code is a modification or plug-in to netbeans (and even then), there's no point in submitting your IDE's source code. It'd be like submitting a copy of MS Word in addition to your term paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a NetBeans Project named `HelloWorld` in your system,let's assume that the default directory of storage of NetBeans Projects is in

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloWorld    // On Windows OS

/home/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorld   //  On *nix(Linux,Unix) based OS
```

If it is different from the above,then please switch to the default directory of the Netbeans Projects.

Select your project folder from that,`HelloWorld` here.

It'll have several directories(folders) inside.

Switch over to `src` folder. All the `.java` files are placed in that directory. Those are the source code in Java. You can open and check and verify those files using any text-editor like Notepad,Gedit,etc.

**NOTE :- DON'T DELETE ANY OTHER FOLDER/FILES** unnecessarily,else,your NetBeans project won't be recognised/won't run properly.